# Rerender is not currently supported with rich text editing enabled

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, richtextarea

I'm trying to implement richText and my datatype is `Text Area (Rich)`
when I click on Save button I get the error

Does Salesforce support Text Area Rich by default?

Error:

> Rerender is not currently supported with rich text editing enabled

[source code](https://github.com/Avinava/custom-rtf):

```
<apex:outputPanel id="op>
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">                      
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">  
                            <c:ckeditor targetclass="mytextarea" toolbar="Knowledge"  />
                            <apex:inputTextarea value="{!ita_background}" styleClass="mytextarea" richText="false" cols="11" rows="9"/>

                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
               </apex:outputPanel>

<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveMe}" reRender="op"  />
```

Comment: Why do you need to rerend the richtext section?

Comment: so once the user click on save button i want to reRender only that section in this case `<apex:outputPanel id="op>`

Comment: Why do I need reRender? the reason it reloads the entire page

Comment: Sorry wrong question, are you doing something in your saveMe method that require to rerend your section. You could reRend="nothing" if you don't need back anything to your page.

Comment: in my saveMe method just saving the data but currently i haveno rerender but as i said that it reloads the entire page which i do not want, i just need to rerender the section that inputTextArea is in as show in my question.